# How to merge arrays of different table entries together?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, unnest

I have a table which keeps track of price changes at different dates:

```
| ID | price           | date       |
|----|-----------------|------------|
| 1  | {118, 123, 144} | 2020/12/05 |
| 2  | {222, 333, 231} | 2020/12/06 |
| 3  | {99, 55, 33}    | 2020/12/07 |
```

I would like to retrieve all prices in a single array ordered by their date so I would get the result like this:

```
| ID | price                              |
|----|------------------------------------|
| 1  | {118,123,144,222,333,231,99,55,33} |
```

How can I achieve this? It seems to me that the challenge is creating a new array or appending values to an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest and re-aggregate with proper ordering:

```
select array_agg(x.val order by t.date, x.rn) as all_prices
from mytable t
cross join lateral unnest(t.price) with ordinality as x(val, rn)
```

One (presumably) important thing is to keep track of the position of each element in the original array, that we can then use as second-level sorting criteria when aggregating.